# XSL - Unable to get all child nodes

Tags: xml, xslt, xsd

I am trying to generate a custom schema (XSD file) using a XSL file but the XSL is not picking up all the data elements from the XML input which I am providing. Please see below:

XML input:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Employees>
   <Employee>
        <Data>
          <Name>Rob</Name>
          <Age>20</Age>
        </Data>
      </Employee>
      <Employee>
        <Data>
          <Name>Sean</Name>
          <Age>50</Age>
          <Department>Accounts</Department>
        </Data>
      </Employee>
</Employees>
```

XSL:

```
<xsl:template match="Data[*]">
      <xs:element name="Data" minOccurs="1">
        <xs:complexType>
        <xs:all minOccurs="0">
          <xsl:call-template name="DataChildren"/>
        </xs:all>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template name="DataChildren">
    <xsl:for-each select="*">
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="local-name() = 'Gender'">
            <xs:element name="Gender" type="Gender" minOccurs="0" />
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="local-name() = 'Age'">
            <xs:element name="Age" type="Age-empty" minOccurs="0" />
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xs:element name="{local-name()}" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
```

XSD output:

```
<xs:element name="Data" minOccurs="1">
   <xs:complexType>
      <xs:all minOccurs="0">
         <xs:element name="Name" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
         <xs:element name="Age" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      </xs:all>
   </xs:complexType>
 </xs:element>
```

If you can see the XSD output above its missing the **Department** node. Looks like its not looping through all the child **Employee** elements rather it only picks up the nodes available in the first child node. Please help.

Comment: You match on a `Data` element, so, given your input sample has two of them, the output should have two `xs:element name="Data"`, one with the `xs:element name="Name"` and `name="Age"` children, the second with the `Name`, `Age`, `Department`.

Comment: @MartinHonnen - Sorry I don't understand.. The output should have only one xs:element name="Data" element with all Name, Age & Department elements.

Comment: That stylesheet snippet, run against the XML sample, will output two `xs:element name="Data"` elements.

Comment: @MartinHonnen - The output should have only one xs:element name="Data" element with Name, Age & Department elements not two.. This is a custom schema which will be run against the user XML so that the user can only have Name and/or Age and/or Department element(s) inside the Data element.

Comment: The result you show can not be the result of the xslt you show us. Please show the complete xsl.

Comment: @SiebeJongebloed - Yes, this is just an excerpt of the actual xsd output.. Its pretty huge. Btw, your last comment is not complete.. Can you please tell me what the match should be ?

Comment: Show minimal but complete samples to allow us to understand and reproduce the problem. That snippet processes both `Data` elements and outputs one `xs:element name="Data"` for each of them. It is not clear which other code you have but matching on a `Data` element and using a `for-each select="*"` on the children will only process the child elements of the currently processed `Data` element. It is not clear how you expect to infer the right structure of the XSD if you process a single `Data`, somehow you need to group them or process all child elements of all `Data` elements and group them.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be completely misguided. Your stylesheet is written with knowledge of the structure of the XML - that is, knowledge of the schema you are trying to generate. Perhaps there are some aspects of the schema you know in advance and other aspects that you want to infer, but if that's the case, you need to explain it to us.

In addition, your code is making no attempt to look at all the `Data` elements, or at all the `Employee` elements, to discover what they have in common. You can only construct a schema for `Data` elements if you look at all the `Data` elements in the input to infer a type that they all conform to.

Finally, there are plenty of tools around for constructing a schema from an instance document. Why aren't you using them?